# Get job id on called method from job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I'm trying to get the job which starts an action in this particular action.

Let me explain.

```
class MyClass
  def go_for_it(delay = true)
    if delay
      delay(run_at: 2.minutes.from_now).go_for_it(false)
    else
      # How can I know if I was called by a DelayedJob AND if yes, which one ?
      puts "I'll do it"
    end

  end
end


my_class = MyClass.new
my_class.delay(run_at: 2.minutes.from_now).go_for_it
```

My aim here is to make restrictions on jobs creation. I don't want `go_for_it` method called twice but this method can delay again itself according to some reasons. If I add those lines to `go_for_it`:

```
calling_method = caller_locations[0].label
job = Delayed::Job.where(queue: "my_queue").first
puts job.payload_object.id
# => id of MyClass if recorded
puts job.payload_object.method_name
# => :go_for_it
```

In the case of `go_for_it` delaying itself, these data are not enough because `job` variable can be itself and then it's not a second different call of `got_for_it`. It's just itself delayed again.

What I need to know here is which job call `run` or `invoke_job` on `go_for_it` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding well, you need to know which job is actually running.

You can use a custom job with a before hook to do an action before running the job, also you'll have totally access to job object at this moment.

Example :

```
class MyClassJob
  def initialize(my_object: MyClass.new)
    @my_object = my_object
  end

  def before(job)
    binding.pry
    another_job = Delayed::Job.where(queue: "my_queue").where('id <> ?', job.id)
  end

  def perform
    @my_object.go_for_it
  end
end

MyClassJob.new().delay.perform
```

Comment: Perfect! In my case, here is my `initialize` method: `initialize(my_instance, method, *args)`. And `perform` does `@my_instance.send(@method, @args)`. Thanks.